# Linear Transformation proof regarding XOR

Tags: vector-spaces, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Suppose that $V$ is a $4$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $T:V\to V$ be an invertible linear map and $W$ be a proper subspace of $V$, such that$$V=W \oplus TW.$$If $T^2W\subseteq W$, then show that $T^2W=W$.

---

I know $$A \oplus B = (A \cup B) \text{\\}(A \cap B) $$

so  $$W \oplus TW = (W \cup TW) \text{\\}(W \cap TW) $$

it is given $ W \subseteq V$

But I am not getting the ultimate proof. How to do that?

**Edit**

My attempt

---

Given,
$$V=W \oplus TW$$ thus

$$ V = W  + TW$$ subject to condition $W \cap TW = 0$

Now,
it is also given $ W \subseteq V$ and $T^2W\subseteq W$

so ,$T^2W\subseteq W \subseteq V$

so,
$T^2W\subseteq W \subseteq W  + TW$

Now what to do? Am I wrong in my proof? :(

Multiple doubts are coming in my head,

is not $T^2 = IV?$
Is not the problem reduced to $VW = W?$

Comment: The $\oplus$ means direct sum (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum), not symmetric difference.

Comment: The claim follows by a dimension argument since $V$ is finite dimensional. The direct sum assumption is not even needed.

Comment: Can you help me solving this question?

Comment: Hint: Since $T$ is invertible, $W$ and $T^2W$ have the same number of dimensions.